# How can I plot multi colour in a single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, simulation

I am reading a text file and I want to plot these columns( y and z) but if x column value is 'out', 6 and 4 point colour should be red. In this logic, there are 6 points in the graph but 4 point should be blue, and other two colour should be red. There are two graph and every pragh has 3 point. How can I do that?

```
#-------input.dat---------
#   x          y     z
# col 1      col 2  col 3
# res          5      5
# out          6      4
# res          7      3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data[] =[]
with open('input.dat', skip_header=2,'r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     for line in lines[2:]:
         data.append(list(line.split()))

y = (data[:, 2])
z = (data[:, 3])

------------------------
plt.plot(float(line[1]),b+)
for  line in enumerate(data)
   if line[0] == 'OUT'
        plt.plot(float(line[1]),r+)
-----------------------
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(y, 'b+', label=" Y figure ")
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(z, 'b+', label=" Z figure ")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Read the documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html